# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (1500001,)

Tags: python, shapes, dimension

I am trying to print 3 different plots, showing 3 different signals.
But I know that my code has several mistakes.
One of them is the reason why I get this error message : "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (1500001,)".

I have already checked similar questions, but I am still unable to solve this problem.
Thank for you help.

Here is the code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

samplingRate = 10000
deltaT = 1./samplingRate

data = np.load('vd59r16d9_data.npy') 
csTimesIdentity = np.load('vd59r16d9_cs_times.npy')

print('Dimensions of data : ', np.shape(data))

time = np.arange(0,150,150/deltaT+1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))

ax0 = fig.add_subplot(311)
ax0.set_title('PFC')
ax0.plot(time-60.,data[0,0,:])

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(312)
ax1.set_title('Amygdala')
ax1.plot(time-60.,data[0,1,:])

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(313)
ax2.set_title('Striatum')
ax2.plot(time-60.,data[0,2,:])
ax2.set_xlabel('time (s)')

plt.show()
```

If you notice other mistakes which are not directly related to this error, please feel free to tell me.

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace of your exception so we can have critical info like on what line the exception was raised?

Comment: The problem comes from the line 18, and is repeated in lines 22 and 26.